# Flash - coordinates keeps reseting to 0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, coordinates

ok I can't make this work no matter what, it keeps resetting coordinates to 0.
I make a ship object on stage and make a class of that ship.

```
public class Ship extends MovieClip {

    private var speedX;
    private var speedY;

    public function Ship() {
        x = 50;
        y = 150;
        trace(x, y);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN ,keyDown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP ,keyUp);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    }
    public function keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent) {
        if(e.keyCode == 37) {
            speedX = -5;
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 38) {
            speedY = -5;
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 39) {
            speedX = 5;
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 40) {
            speedY = 5;
        }
    }

    public function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent) {
        trace (x,y);
        if(e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39) {
            speedX = 0;
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40) {
            speedY = 0;
        }
    }

    public function update(e:Event) {
        x += speedX;
        y += speedY;
    }

}
```

here I set coordinates to 50, 150, the trace shows it right, but it still doesn't work.
the game is working fine except coordinates, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: which key are you using to test it?  What is the output of your trace on key up?  Can you add a trace to update, and let me know what you see?  When you say resets to 0, do you mean 50,150, or you mean 0,0?

Comment: it sets to 0,0 only when the game starts, everything else past that is fine

Comment: Ah, so it starts at 0,0, then it moves fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that this will help, but I would explicitly set the update speed to 0 in the Ship() function.

I would also set the position, based on where you placed it, so that you can just place it in the scene, and then it will start from that location.

```
public function Ship() {
    speedX = 0
    speedY = 0
    trace(x, y);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN ,keyDown);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP ,keyUp);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
}
```

Comment: `x = this._x` is not recognized by program, but `x = this.x` seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Waras the line `x = this.x;` and the other with `y` doesn't do anything at all, because it assigns the value of the variable to the variable. You can delete those lines. The part that solves the problem is `speedX = 0` which sets the values to some defined value. Try to `trace(speedX)` in the constructor of `Ship` in your old code to see what value they had there. Rule of thumb: Always specify the type and value for your variables.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this code on my machine and it works fine. Are there any parts of the code that you're not including?

I also changed the class to accept the main stage object as a parameter. This might solve the problem you're having:

```
public function Ship(pStage:DisplayObjectContainer):void
{
    x = 50;
    y = 150;
    trace(x, y);
    pStage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
    pStage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
    pStage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
}
```

Wherever you initialize the Ship object, make sure you're passing the stage object from your Main class. This has worked for me with all of my AS3 projects.

Comment: how do I make this 'pStage'? do I need main class for this to work?

Comment: nevermind figured it out, it's just an empty movieClip, it's kinda useful, but that doesn't fix the issue here, it's speed thats causing the coordinates to reset.